# where is the second positional argument?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm not sure if I quite understand what this error is about...

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
    __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
 File "/home/react_app/fastapi/app/schemas.py", line 73, in <module>
    sch = SellSideCustomer(jsond)
```

This is my code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel as _BaseModel, Field, create_model
from typing import Dict, List, Union, Tuple, Optional


class SellSideCreds(_BaseModel):
    user_name   :   str
    user_pass   :   str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class SellSideCustomer(_BaseModel):
    creds   :   Dict[str, SellSideCreds]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


jsond = {"creds":
                {
                "user_name":"mrhowdy",
                "user_pass":"heythere"
                }
        }

sch = SellSideCustomer(jsond)
print(sch)
```

I get what a positional argument is in the context of a function, but not sure how `jsond` has more than 1...which is just the whole dictionary...

**Note:**
the `__init__()` comes from `pydantic` I assume, because I've never written one of those in my life..I'm new to this.

Comment: Replace `_BaseModel` with `pedantic.BaseModel` (and import `typing.Dict`), and this is a reproducible example. `SellSideCustomer(json)` raises the `TypeError` shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` takes one *positional* argument (`self`); the credentials must be passed as a keyword argument:

```
>>> SellSideCustomer(creds=jsond)
SellSideCustomer(creds={'creds': SellSideCreds(user_name='mrhowdy', user_pass='heythere')})
```

Comment: this makes sense! thank you!! so, if i had two 'keys' for the SellSideCustomer schema, then i could have two keyword arguments, right? for example, creds='stuff', newkey='alsostuff'

Comment: Correct. Try calling `SellSideCreds` directly: `SellSideCreds("foo", "bar")` will complain that you gave it 3 positional arguments, not 1, while `SellSideCreds(user_name="foo", user_pass="bar")` will work fine.